# Accepting binary data in asp net controller

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, controller

I am struggling with binding of binary data sent in the body of http request.

I have the following controller in Asp Net core (NetCore 2.1):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("image/png", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff)]
    [Route("test")]
    public IActionResult Test(IFormFile file)
    {
        return Ok(file.Length);
    }
```

The aim is to receive the stream of byte and bind it to a parameter named 'file'. The problem is that the IFormFile variable is null. In fact by placing a breakpoint inside the controller, the Route works perfectly but it raises a null pointer exception as soon as I try to access 'file' variable.

My doubts are concerned with the way it works. If I access to Request object I am able to read the stream of data without problems. But I don't think it is the right way to do this.
Example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("image/png", "image/bmp", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff)]
    [Route("test")]
    public IActionResult Test(IFormFile binary)
    {
        var x = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Request.Body);
        x.Save(".\\file.bmp");
        return Ok("Image height: " + x.Height.ToString());
    }
```

How can I bind the data sent as binary inside my controllers?

The following is an example of request sent by postman:
[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB1uU.png)
[raw request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pyaY.png)

P.S. I am bonded to receive data as binary although I know that it would be better to receive it inside a multipart-form

Comment: If you want to bind binary to IFormFile binary,you can try to use [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: @YiyiYou thanks for the suggestion but I have definitely found what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution right there: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers?Page=2

What I was looking for was a way to bind the raw Request.Body Stream to a parameter of the controller and it was so easy.

I have just created a custom formatter as below:

```
public class RawRequestBodyFormatter : InputFormatter
{
  public RawRequestBodyFormatter()
  {
    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/bmp"));
  }


/// <summary>
/// Allow image/bmp and no content type to
/// be processed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public override Boolean CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
{
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "image/bmp")
        return true;

    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Handle bmp images
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "image/bmp")
    {
        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(request.Body);
    }

    return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
}
```

And then added the respective option to my app

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new 
RawRequestBodyFormatter())
```

Now the following Controller is fully working!

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("image/png", "image/bmp", System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff)]
[Route("test")]
//[JwtAuthenticationAttribute]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody]Stream file)
{
     var x = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file);
     x.Save(".\\file.bmp");
     return Ok("Image height: " + x.Height.ToString());
}
```